# Why compilation fails for the first time but succeedes the second time?

Tags: delphi, compilation, 32-bit, delphi-10.2-tokyo

This question is about Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, 32-bit compilator.

When I change interface of specific unit (`A`), compile fails in `unit B` the first time. When I rerun the compilation, it proceeds (sometimes only the third compilation works). If I build the project, or delete all `.dcu` files (I guess only "bad" ones need to be deleted), everything works just fine. This is not such a big problem for manual compilation, but automatic compilation could be seriously impeded. This happens with few other units (and the first unit that caused this problem stopped causing it after some change, but it is hard to say which change and in which file).

It happens with mulitple methods of compilation - directly with RAD studio, with external compilation allowed, with msbuild.

It fails with this messages:

```
    [dcc32 Error] B(x): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Some_Class_From_Unit_A'
    [dcc32 Error] B(y): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Other_Class_From_Unit_A'
    [dcc32 Error] B(z): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
    ...bunch of E2066 Missing operator or semicolon...
```

When I delete `C.dcu`, compile fails in `unit D` with missing references to `unit E`, but editing `unit E` directly doesn't cause similar compilation fail.

All units are referenced by name only, paths are in `.dproj` files.

There are multiple cycles in the source code structure, but none of the interface-interface-interface variety (that should't compile, right?). I need some guidelines on what to look for.

My theory: `unit A` has been changed so it is scheduled to be recompiled; `unit B` uses `unit A` so it is also scheduled for recompile; `unit A` would normally be compiled before `unit B` but the compiler had decided that `unit B` goes first (because of some dependency cycle); `unit B` looks for compiled `unit A` but there is no such thing yet - thus the symbols from `unit A` are deemed missing.

Is my theory right? If so, how do we avoid this problem? I was unable to find a way of enforcing some compile order.

Comment: Make a graph with all of your units and their mutual dependencies.  If it looks like a tangled mess, you could probably do with some refactoring - most likely this is a convoluted circular reference problem.  Find the circles and turn them into trees.

Comment: What Delphi version?

Comment: 1) Which version of Delphi? 2) "automatic" compilation should be doing a full `Build` anyway. FWIW, whenever I feel the need to add a `uses` clause to the `implementation` section, I tend to spawn off a new unit instead, just to avoid circular reference issues as J brings up.

Comment: @JerryDodge: 1) - edited; 2) I would rather use compile, because full build will take multiple minutes.

Comment: @J...: Yeah, it is a messy entanglement... decirculariazation it is then...

Comment: @J... " Find the circles and turn them into trees" That sounds a bit like from a motivational poster. <g>

Comment: @Rudy Like a Bob Ross video... "Turn those circles into happy little trees..."

Comment: @Jerry: So we don't have exceptions or AVs anymore, just happy little accidents? And every tree needs a friend (or two).

Comment: @JerryDodge /Rudy - I think you guys have been too long into the cadmium red.

Comment: Alizarin crimson is my favourite.

Comment: There is a bug somewhere in Delphi compiler which affects 10.2 Tokyo and also 10.3 Rio (at least). I have the exact same issue with different projects. If I edit a core unit referenced by many others, compilation might fail because of some random(?) "undeclared identified" error. If, instead of just hitting compile I hit build, the compiler works flawlessly. Unfortunately, one of the projects is a huge  (5 MLOC) and I believe that the complexity of the source code is part of the puzzle. The same project compiles and builds fine in XE2.

Comment: Is this affecting 64bit, 32bit or both? With a bigger project we have long experienced compiling instabilities in 64bit, using **Project > Options > Delphi Compiler > Use MSBuild externally (True)** did solve that. Or just working in 32bit as a developer.